# Passport.js Google Logout User Persists

Tags: javascript, node.js, passport.js

I am using Passport.js on an application with Express.  I have implemented the local and google login strategies.  Those aspects work correctly for login.  My issue is with the logout.

For the local strategy, if I login and logout the built in Passport logout function works correctly below and removes the "user" from the session.  When I login and then logout with the Google strategy, the "user" persists in the session/store.  In Chrome, if I clear all of the Google cookies from the browser the application then "logs out" the user.

I have tried every permutation of this I can find on SO or Googling, but I can not find the correct method to actually logout a user who logs in via the Google strategy?

```
// LOGOUT
//From the route

router.get('/logout', function(req, res){
    req.session.destroy(function(err) {
    res.clearCookie('connect.sid');
        res.clearCookie('_gid');
        res.clearCookie('_ga');
        req.logOut();
        req.user=null
    res.redirect('/');
    });
});
```

This is from app.js

```
app.use(session({
  resave: true,
  saveUninitialized: true
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the best way, but if someone comes across this, in the page that the logout route redirects to I am manually setting user to be null on the client side if req.user does not exist on the server.  This seemed to do the trick. As an example:

```
//HOME PAGE
router.get(['/','/'], function(req, res, next) {
    if (req.user){
      res.render('index.pug', {
      user: req.user,
      message: req.flash('loginMessage'),
    });
  } else {
        res.render('index.pug', {
            user: null,
            message: req.flash('loginMessage'),
        });
  }
});
```

Not sure why in the Google method that variable hangs on in the client side, but it does.